# How to get id's based on in between time using MySql

Tags: mysql, node.js, select, left-join

I want to get cubbersId based on in between  time

**This is my table:** table name `cubbersavailability`

```
+---------------------------------------+
|cubbersId  |   fromTime    |   toTime   |
+---------------------------------------+
|   1       |   09:30:00    |   18:30:00 |
|   1       |   09:30:00    |   18:30:00 |
|   1       |   09:30:00    |   18:30:00 |
|   1       |   09:30:00    |   12:30:00 |
+----------------------------------------+
```

In the above table cubbersIsd have some times.

**Conditions**

1. If am choose `fromTime` as `10:30:00` and `toTime` as `12:00:00` means get last 1 columns
2. If am choose `fromTime` as `08:30:00` and `toTime` as `16:00:00` means don't select the columns
3. If am choose `fromTime` as `10:30:00` and `toTime` as `20:00:00` means don't select the columns
4. If am choose `fromTime` as `08:30:00` and `toTime` as `20:00:00` means don't select the columns

I tried this query but this not supported:

```
SELECT 
    c.cubbersId, 
    shopAvailTime.fromTime, 
    shopAvailTime.toTime 
FROM cubbers c 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT * FROM cubbersavailability ca WHERE CAST('08:30:00' as time) < ca.toTime AND CAST('12:00:00' as time) > ca.fromTime ) as shopAvailTime ON (c.cubbersId = shopAvailTime.cubbersId) 
WHERE c.cubbersId = 1
```

But it get all the list 
[image]

> Note: this question already asked but that not help my question;

Comment: I wonder if you're making this vastly more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @Strawberry: Send me your contact details

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.cubbersId
     , x.fromTime
     , x.toTime 
  FROM cubbersavailability x 
 WHERE '08:30:00' >= x.fromTime
   AND '12:00:00' <= x.toTime
   AND x.cubbersId = 1
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong there. Note however that your table appears to be missing a PRIMARY KEY, which could well prove problematic in due course.